# How does the Network work if I add route address as its own ip

Tags: networking, ip, routing

My Window PC has ip address `10.10.70.89` and default gateway is `10.10.191.1`.

```
route ADD 192.168.30.0 MASK 255.255.255.0  10.10.70.89
```

I've tried to execute the above command.
So route table has my own pc's ip address.
When trying to communicate with PC in subnet,`192.168.30.0`, in my PC,
how does it work?
Please let me know.
I'm newbie to network.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, using yourself as the gateway actually creates an *on-link* route, aka local subnet route (just as if there was no gateway at all). The system will directly send ARP requests for 192.168.30.x over the matching interface.

(For example, if 10.10.70.89 belongs to interface #3, then it's equivalent to `route add 192.168.30.0 mask 255.255.255.0 if 3`.)

I think this style was originally inherited from BSD; I've also seen it on Solaris.